# Acceder a dato miembro de la instancia de una clase Padre desde el Hijo | Python

Tags: python, poo

Tengo el siguiente código donde instancio una clase del tipo NeuralNet, y a esta a su vez contiene una subclase para la instanciación de una clase Layer.

```
NN=NeuralNet(input_data,output_data,stop_precision=0.01)
NN.add_layer(20,'relu')

class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self,input_data,output_data,stop_precision=0.1):
       * bla bla
       * bla bla
       #Atributo quiero acceder desde la clase hija
       self.input_data=input_data


    def add_layer(self,number_neurons,activation_function,id_layer=None):
       layer_temp=self.Layer(**mando los parametros**)
       #A través de este método intento acceder
       layer_temp.initialize_data()

    class Layer:
       def __init__(self,number_conexions,number_neurons,activation_function,id_layer):
           * bla bla
           * bla bla
        def initialize_data(self):
           if self.id_layer=='input_layer':
              #Aqui he intentado acceder al atributo input_data
              self.W=super().NeuralNetwork.input_data
              self.W=NeuralNetwork.input_data
```

Entonces mi pregunta es, puedo acceder al atributo input_data de la instanciación de la clase NeuralNet sin tener que pasársela como parámetro a las funciones para la instanciación de la clase Layer ?
A su vez se me generan otras dudas como : La clase Layer al estar dentro de la clase NeuralNet, es una subclase ? está haciendo una herencia ya ? subclase y herencia son lo mismo en python?

Comment: trata de hacer tu pregunta más especifica

Comment: Tu puedes instanciar la segunda clase (o subclase) sin tener que *instanciar a la primera*  La segunda clase no hereda nada de la primera, pero si puede llamar a sus métodos o atributos si se instancia a la primera (para los métodos y atributos de instancia)

Comment: Pero puedo llamar los métodos y atributos de la instancia de la primera clase, desde la segunda ? Lo que trato es acceder al atributo "input_data" de la primera clase o clase padre NeuralNet, desde el método "initialize_data" de la clase Layer

Comment: si pero tendras que instanciarla en la segunda clase, lo mejor es usar herencia.